# Überhaupt keines! / Überhaupt kein Wasser!

Tags: colloquial

Ist der Satz bzw. die Ergänzung „Überhaupt keines!“ gebräuchlich? Oder würde man nur „Überhaupt kein Wasser!“ hinzufügen?

> In der Kantine ist kein Wasser! Überhaupt keines!

Comment: Ich würde sagen "Überhaupt keins!". Was genau ist mit "In der Kantine *ist kein Wasser*!" gemeint? Mineralwasser, Leitungswasser, Wasser von einer Überschwemmung? In den ersten zwei Fällen würde ich eher "In der Kantine *gibt es* kein Wasser!" oder im letzten "... steht kein Wasser" verwenden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In der Kantine gibt es kein Wasser. Gar keins!

ist die übliche Art, so etwas zu formulieren.

Comment: Aber sollte man *keines* statt *keins* in formellen Fällen schreiben?

Comment: In Deutsch-Prüfungen solltest du „keines“ schreiben.

Comment: Danke vielmals.

Answer (score 2):

Die beiden Sätze sind vollkommen richtig und klingen normal. Die bestehende Antwort und der bestehende Kommentar haben Recht, dass "gibt es" statt "ist" etwas natürlicher klingt, dass man statt "überhaupt" auch "gar" sagen kann und dass man "keines" zu "keins" verkürzen kann. Das bedeutet nicht, dass die Sätze, so wie sie in der Frage formuliert sind, ungewöhnlich wären.